# Tweepyのapi.update_profile_background_imageのみエラーになる

Tags: python, python3, api, twitter

### 環境

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (MacOS catalina上のvirtual-box/vagrantで仮想構築)
Python: ver3.8.6
※**ローカルのMacOS上でも同様のエラーが発生**している

### 事象

TwitterのAPIキー(カスタマーキー、カスタマーシークレット、アクセストークン、アクセストークンシークレットのそれぞれ)を入手し、
自分のTwitterアカウントのアイコンとバックグラウンドイメージ(バナー/アイコンの上の画像)を変更しようと考えました。

アイコンの変更に関しては下記のコードで問題なく行うことが出来ました。

```
import os
import tweepy

CK = os.environ['CUS_KEY']
CS = os.environ['CUS_KEY_SECRET']
AT = os.environ['ACS_TOKEN']
AS = os.environ['ACS_TOKEN_SECRET']

def create_api():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CK, CS)
    auth.set_access_token(AT, AS)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    return api

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api = create_api()
    # the file path 
    filename = "Monet_La_Gourneuiere.jpg"
    api.update_profile_image(filename)
```

しかし**バックグラウンドイメージの変更は下記コードでは上手くいきませんでした。**

```
import os
import tweepy

CK = os.environ['CUS_KEY']
CS = os.environ['CUS_KEY_SECRET']
AT = os.environ['ACS_TOKEN']
AS = os.environ['ACS_TOKEN_SECRET']

def create_api():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CK, CS)
    auth.set_access_token(AT, AS)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    return api

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api = create_api()
    # the file path 
    filename = "Monet_La_Gourneuiere.jpg"
    # updating the background picture 
    api.update_profile_background_image(filename)
```

エラーは下記の通りで、ページが見つからない旨記されていました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
    api.update_profile_background_image(hoge)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 708, in update_profile_background_image
    return bind_api(
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 252, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 234, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist', 'code': 34}]
```

上記エラーの解決方法がどうしてもわからず、アドバイス/回答等いただけると幸いです。
以上、よろしくお願いします。

### *補足1

アイコンの変更だけでなく、tweet[update_status("")]やプロフィール変更[update_profile()]は問題なく
使用出来ます。

### ※補足2:Ubuntu上での環境構築は下記の通り

```
$ sudo apt install git gcc make openssl libssl-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev
$ git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
$ echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ pyenv install 3.8.6
$ pip install tweepy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決。(Twitterで別の方に教えていただけました。)

```
api.update_profile_banner(hoge)
```

を使用すれば問題なくバックグラウンドイメージを修正出来る。

参考：[POST account/update_profile_banner Twitter Developer公式](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/post-account-update_profile_banner)